# Gravity's Rainbow

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

What is it? I've seen it in context of a few research papers such as

*[Absence of black holes at LHC due to gravity's rainbow](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269315001562)*
 and *[Thermodynamics of black holes in gravity’s rainbow
formalisms](http://digital.csic.es/bitstream/10261/15057/1/Gal%C3%A1n.pdf)*

My best conjecture is that it's a framework of dimension higher than 3, with gravity spilling, or "rainbowing" into higher dimensions manifesting slightly differently. Can anyone shed any light on this one?

Comment: Doesn't the second link explain that in the passages following *"In the following, we will concentrate our attention on the so-called gravity’s rainbow proposal
of Magueijo and Smolin for the realization of the effects of DSR in the spacetime geometry [12],
as well as on a variant of it that is based on a canonical implementation of the DSR theories
[13]."*? (And it even gives the original reference for it! (Smolin/Maguejio))

Comment: Good starting point! Thank you kindly! I'm going to follow that trail, and answer the question with the details of it for those who may have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe gravity's rainbow relates to gravitational lensing, which can be likened to refraction. In normal refraction we see a rainbow spectrum, because the degree of refraction depends on the photon E=hf energy. However in gravitational lensing, we do not. Gravity's rainbow is a speculation that we might. I'm not fond of it because it's akin to saying different objects fall at different speeds, and nor am I fond of the black hole paper you mention because it ignores general relativity and could be construed as scaremongering that threatens LHC experimentation. Search the [ArXiv](http://arxiv.org/find/grp_physics/1/ti:+AND+gravity+rainbow/0/1/0/all/0/1) for papers including http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9411018.

Comment: It's a type of modification to special relativity per that not only prescribes and invariant velocity, but also an invariant length/mass scale ( Planck Length/Mass ) which generates the name Doubly Special Relativity or DSR ( Deformed Special Relativity ) which is really only apparent at high energy regimes where standard relativity breaks down..

Comment: See [Sabine Hossenfelder's blog](http://backreaction.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/no-lhc-will-not-make-contact-with.html) on the LHC black hole paper. She wasn't too keen on it either!

Comment: I see that lol The papers I linked were just used as mere mentions of the subject in--arbitrary--context. The key concern is not the absence of black holes at LHC, but the concept of gravity's rainbow itself. I followed the paper trail and found the answer I was looking for in a very quaint paper here: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0312140 ! The paper you provided also seems to be highly informative as well! I'll use the info from them both to form an explicit answer!